# On html page load, process something on server side and send a result back to html page

Tags: html, iframe, server-side, code-behind, serverside-javascript

I need to do something that can only be processed on server side and not by just using javascript on the html page. I'm already using this process for my other aspx pages. However, this time I need to make this work on an html page.

The workaround that I have done so far is to have an iframe somewhere in my html page that points to an aspx page. I do the process on its code behind and save what I need on a hidden field in the iframe. I can now get that value from the iframe and use it on my html page.

It works but I'm thinking that there might be a simpler approach in doing this without having to create a new aspx page just for processing. Is there another way to accomplish this?

UPDATE: To be specific, I need to get the location(country) of the user on page load in order to change the css accordingly. I know there are a lot of sites that I can connect to on my page to do this but I don't know which one is secured. Also, we already have our own method to this for our aspx pages so I want to use that instead. Hope this update helps.

Comment: simpler approach is using `ajax`

Comment: could you please give an example on how to do it by ajax? the method for processing is already done. i just need to be able to call it on the html.

Comment: It sounds like the thing that would help you is AJAX, but it's hard to tell what the ideal solution because your current situation isn't described in much detail. For instance: why can't you just deliver all the information in the requested page (why do you need to make another request)? Why do you need a hidden input? Can you show us the essential parts of your existing code and explain why it does what it does?

Comment: @jbdeguzman could you show your code first?

Comment: Sorry if the description lacks information in order for you to answer it. But I think all of you already did. I cannot show my code so I need to try doing it on my own. I'll do my research and try using AJAX. Thanks guys!

Comment: Sometimes I have code that I cannot post on StackOverflow, so I modify it a bit for brevity and to not reveal client info etc.. Part of asking questions here is about providing us with the info we need to help you. As you can see we are all eager to help. But you are going to get a lot of downvotes by doing things in this manner. just an FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do what I think you are explaining. Your question was not very clear.

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
        // Do something interesting here.
      }
    });
```

HTML

```
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>Calling a page method with jQuery</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Default.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="Result">Click here for the time.</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
      $("#Result").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
          data: "{}",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(msg) {
            // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
            $("#Result").text(msg.d);
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

But again I really have no idea what you are trying to do. You were really vague.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simpler approach is ajax.

This is pseudo javascript code...

```
window.onload = function(){
    ajax.open("your server url");
    ajax.on("success",function(){
        alert("okay, done.");
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using iFrame for the process you have requested, is not recommended.

Consider including AJAX to route your request to a server resource. In your case it should be an asp page.

Here's a beginners guide to using ajax with asp 
http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ajax_asp.asp

PS: When using AJAX make sure you are aware about

- Cross Domain Requests http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Here's a pseudo code for you to work on:

```
<script>
function funcName(){
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
 document.getElementById("<yourOwnElement'sID>").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","serverResource.asp?q="+<parameters>,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```